# Unable to login to Stack Exchange chat

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

I am using Google Chrome 7.0.517.41. The cookie settings for my browser is: "Allow local data to be saved (recommended)." I am already signed into Web Applications SE, but I still can't log in to https://chat.stackexchange.com/. I also tried using http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/, but nothing happens. How can I log in into chat?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? The page is blank?

Comment: You may be able to get help at this MSO chatroom: [Login problems on Chat.SE](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/296/login-problems-on-chat-se)

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: It only redirects me to chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen (there is no site-specific chat.webapps.stackexchange.com). What happens when you go to chat.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to get

```
Your login data seems too old; please log in to any StackExchange site to refresh it.
```

when trying to log in to https://chat.stackexchange.com. It only worked after doing the [global logout](https://stackexchange.com/users/logout/global). Local logout didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Either Marc or balpha once said it doesn't matter that you're logged in, it matters **when** you logged in.  Try logging out of the sites and then logging back in and trying chat.

Comment: You usually get a message about your login data being too old though

Comment: True.  I'm not sure what is actually happening though.

Comment: Still problem is not solved.

Comment: @chanchal1987, Please provide details about what is happening?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: No error messages. Only showing "Log In" link in the top of the page.

Comment: @cha What happens when you click it?

Comment: Problem is automatically solved after refreshing the chat page some time.

Comment: @cha I'm not entirely sure that you're having a problem at all. You're not logged in to chat, and then you click "login" and you are? That's what's supposed to happen

Comment: I clicked login several times. Its opened an Login page and asking me to log in any of the stackexchange site. I don't know why this problem solved automatically.